# Insert data from temp table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert data from multiple table. From that one of the table is temp table in which it comes multiple data i.e. 46 and 47 whose field name is productid. But it is not inserting in another table by multiple condition.

Here is my query :

```
Insert into #temp
    select Product.Id 
    from Product 
    left outer join In_abc_Product ON In_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
    where In_abc_Product.ID IS NULL

BEGIN
    select * from #temp

    --Insert data into In_abc_Product where condition is p.Deleted = 'False' or p.Published = 'True' or  VisibleIndividually = 'True'
        Insert into In_abc_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select tmp.productid,1,0,GETDATE(),s.Id,l.Id from  Language l, Store s, #temp tmp left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = tmp.productid
        left join product p on p.id = isp.ProductId  where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'False' or p.Published = 'True' or  VisibleIndividually = 'True'

    --Insert data into In_abc_Product where condition is p.Deleted = 'True' or p.Published = 'False' or  VisibleIndividually = 'False'
        Insert into Incremental_Solr_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select tmp.productid,1,0,GETDATE(),s.Id,l.Id from  Language l, Store s, #temp tmp left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = tmp.productid
        left join product p on p.id = isp.ProductId where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'True' or p.Published = 'False' or  VisibleIndividually = 'False'

    END
END
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Does the select statement in the insert clause return something? If yes, you're rollbacking your transaction, if not, then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

--Please check this out it may reach upto your requirement.

```
    Insert into #temp
select Product.Id from Product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN In_abc_Product ON In_abc_Product.ID = Product.ID
WHERE In_abc_Product.ID IS NULL

    BEGIN
    select * from #temp

Insert into In_abc_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select tmp.productid,1,0,GETDATE(),(SELECT S.Id FROM Store s),(SELECT l.Id  Language l)
        from   #temp tmp 
        left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = tmp.productid
        left join product p on p.id = isp.ProductId  
        where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'False' or p.Published = 'True' or  VisibleIndividually = 'True'


            Insert into Incremental_Solr_Product(ProductId, SolrStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId,LanguageId) 
        select tmp.productid,1,0,GETDATE(),(select s.Id from Store s),(select l.Id from Language l)
        from   #temp tmp 
        left join Incremental_Solr_Product isp on isp.ProductId = tmp.productid
        left join product p on p.id = isp.ProductId where isp.Id is NULL and p.Deleted = 'True' or p.Published = 'False' or  VisibleIndividually = 'False'

            END
END
```

Comment: nop it is not working it is coming output same as my code